# Adding a Link in my React project crashes the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css

So I'm trying to add a Link to the Ul menus that I already made. Every time I try to somehow make a ListItem a link it crashes the page. I've got my BrowserRouter, Routes, and Route setup on my app.jsx page. The page I'm working with is my Navbar page, and I did import Link on it. I've tried wrapping the ListItem in the Link. Wrapping the Link in the ListItem. Replacing the ListItem with just the Link. Nothing. I'm still fairly new to React and so this is really bugging me that I've spent hours on this today. Thanks in advance.

```js
import React from 'react'
import './index.css'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import About from './Components/About'
import Projects from './Components/Projects'
import Skills from './Components/Skills'
import Contact from './Components/Contact'

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/projects" element={<Projects />} />
            <Route path="/skills" element={<Skills />} />
            <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {AiOutlineClose, AiOutlineMenu} from 'react-icons/ai'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import About from './About'

const Navbar = () => {

    const [nav, setNav] = useState(true)

    const handleNav = () => {
        setNav(!nav)
    }

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-between items-center h-24 max-w-[1240px] mx-auto px-4 text-blue font-bold">
        <h1 className="w-full text-3xl font-bold text-[#4bb3f8] hover:scale-105 duration-300">TIM WARD</h1>
        <ul className="hidden md:flex text-[#4bb3f8]">
            <li className="p-4">MAIN</li>
            <li className="p-4">ABOUT</li>
            <li className="p-4">SKILLS</li>
            <li className="p-4">PROJECTS</li>
            <li className="p-4">CONTACT</li>
        </ul>
        <div onClick={handleNav} className="block md:hidden">
            {!nav ? <AiOutlineClose size={20} color='#4bb3f8'/> : <AiOutlineMenu size={20} color='#4bb3f8'/>}
        </div>
        <div className={!nav ? "fixed left-0 top-0 w-[60%] h-full border-r border-r-gray-900 bg-[#4bb3f8] ease-in-out duration-200" : "fixed left-[-100%]"}>
          <h1 className="w-full text-3xl font-bold text-[#4bb3f8] m-4">TIM WARD</h1>
          <ul className="uppercase p-4">
            <li className="p-4 border-b border-gray-600">MAIN</li>
            <li className="p-4 border-b border-gray-600">ABOUT</li>
            <li className="p-4 border-b border-gray-600">SKILLS</li>
            <li className="p-4 border-b border-gray-600">PROJECTS</li>
            <li className="p-4 border-b border-gray-600">CONTACT</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: Please include the text relevant code directly in the post, not as an image.

Comment: Sorry @rioV8. Fixed it.

Comment: When the page crashes, what did u see in console?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I don't notice anything in the terminal getting flagged.

Comment: @Andy I've tried deleting it. I've tried replacing my whole <div> field in Navbar and just a <Link> itself doesn't even show up. Gotta be something stupid on my end I'm just completely overlooking.

Comment: @Andy took a break to go pick up my kid, and after I got back home it was solved in 5 minutes…. The <Navbar /> wasn’t in the <BrowserRouter>…. My first taste of half a day being spent on something so minor!